# Запуск скрипта питон в скрипте баш

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Решил более подробно изложить ситуацию.

Есть баш скрипт который делает всякие вычисления, и определяет переменные, которые затем будут заданы в виде параметров у питон скрипта

B4_random.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
#Укажи имя проекта
Proekt="B4"
#Укажи файл с диапазонами в формате /32
IP="IP_1"
#Укажи колличество рандомных диапазанов
IP_Random="5"
#Сколько логинов ты хочешь сгенирировать
Logins_Random="1"
#Укажем имена пользывателей которое обязательно будут задействованы
#Standart_Logins="admin"
#Сколько паролей ты хочешь сгенирировать
Passwords_Random="1"
#Какой протокол будем брутить
Target="-b rdp"
#Сколько потоков ты хочешь задействовать
Potok="-n 2000"
#Удаляем дубликаты диапазонов
rm ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Диапазоны/crow/$Proekt
#Генерируем диапазоны
cat | shuf -n $IP_Random ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Диапазоны/crow/$IP >> ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Диапазоны/crow/$Proekt &
#Удаляем дубликаты логинов
rm ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/logins/BOSS/$Proekt
#Генерируем логины
cat | shuf -n $Logins_Random ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/logins/BOSS/LOGINS >> ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/logins/BOSS/$Proekt &
#Удаляем дубликаты паролей
rm ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/passwds/BOSS/$Proekt
#Генерируем пароли
cat | shuf -n $Passwords_Random ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/passwds/BOSS/PASSWORDS >> ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/passwds/BOSS/$Proekt &
#Приступаем к бруту
cd ..
set -x
python crowbar.py -v $Potok $Target -S ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Диапазоны/crow/$Proekt -U ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/logins/BOSS/$Proekt -C ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/passwds/BOSS/$Proekt -o ~/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Результат/$Proekt
echo "OK !!!"
```

при выполнении ./B4_random, set -x показывает

```
python crowbar.py -v -n 2000 -b rdp -S /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Диапазоны/crow/B4 -U /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/logins/BOSS/B4 -C /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/passwds/BOSS/B4 -o /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Результат/B4
```

При запуске BASH скрипта, не чувствуется работа скрипта

```
+ python crowbar.py -v -n 2000 -b rdp -S /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Диапазоны/crow/B4 -U /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/logins/BOSS/B4 -C /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/passwds/BOSS/B4 -o /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Результат/B4
2016-01-14 17:26:09 START
2016-01-14 17:26:11 STOP
No result is found ...
+ echo 'OK !!!'
OK !!!
```

Но если я копирую отлов set -x

```
python crowbar.py -v -n 2000 -b rdp -S /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Диапазоны/crow/B4 -U /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/logins/BOSS/B4 -C /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Словари/passwds/BOSS/B4 -o /home/user/Yandex.Disk/Задачи/_Результат/B4
```

и выполняю, то вывод будет такой:

```
2016-01-14 17:37:43 START
2016-01-14 17:37:43 LOG-RDP: 54.152.173.150:3389 - fullered:Cedric721
2016-01-14 17:37:43 LOG-RDP: 108.186.32.92:3389 - fullered:Cedric721
2016-01-14 17:37:43 LOG-RDP: 72.8.145.120:3389 - fullered:Cedric721
2016-01-14 17:37:43 LOG-RDP: 128.122.7.35:3389 - fullered:Cedric721
2016-01-14 17:37:43 LOG-RDP: 71.42.203.61:3389 - fullered:Cedric721
2016-01-14 17:39:51 STOP
No result is found ...
```

Как заставить БАШ скрипт так же подробно выводить отчёт ? Или вообще заставить работать ...

Comment: не совсем понятно в чем проблема, вы хотите чтобы питон отобразил команды, которые он выполнил? а он такое может?

Comment: @BOPOH можно конечно и [очень подробно](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tracing). Но в большинстве случаев следует просто в лог писать (`logging`) события в программе, [пример: `log()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32803324/4279)

Comment: вы уверены, что вы видите как stdout так и stderr? Проблема что не весь вывод печатается или что печатается весь вывод, но только в конце?

Comment: @jfs, я про другое, у меня есть скрипт `print (123)` - больше ничего нет. Можно ли указав определенную опцию заставить питон показать операции, которые он совершил, т.е. на экране будет не только `123`, но и `print (123)`? Судя по вопросу (*set - x не помогает... показывает полную команду запуска*), автора именно это интересует. Т.е. если без каких-либо телодвижений (типа той библиотеки) этого сделать нельзя, то это и будет ответом

Comment: Хотя, возможно, ошибаюсь и интересует не скрипт питона, а то, каким образом параметры, которые передаются в этот скрипт, получены. Но автор молчит че-то. Лучше бы пример привел того, что есть и того, что ожидает

Comment: @BOPOH я понимаю, я рассказываю что нужно делать, если вы на Питоне разрабатываете. На Питоне дополнительная функциональность обычно реализована с помощью кода на Питоне и вы всегда можете выполнить дополнительный код с помощью PYTHONSTARTUP, sitecustomize, usercustomize или явно запускающий модуль указать, например, `python -mrun your_script.py` (как это делать win-unicode-console пакет), если нельзя дочерний скрипт менять.

Comment: python -mrun your_script.py
Пишет ошибку
/usr/bin/python: No module named run.__main__; 'run' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: @3amunyk `python -mrun` это просто пример из фактически существующего кода. Буквально вам его бессмысленно запускать: задача `win-unicode-console` пакета печатать произвольный Unicode в консоле на Винде -- этот пакет не работает на Linux. Целью [упоминания `python -mrun`] является показать, что есть реальный код, который использует запускающие скрипты, которые произвольный Питон-код могут выполнить. Таким образом изменение исходного скрипта (`your_script.py`) не обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

этот ответ был актуален для [первоначальной версии вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/482188/2)

---

внутренняя команда оболочки (*shell*) `set -x` [определена в стандарте posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) и приводит к тому, что оболочка (в вашем случае — *bash*) перед выполнением каждой команды (фактически — строки в *shell-скрипте*) выводит в *stderr* полный текст команды, с уже подставленными значениями переменных.

на интерпретатор *python*, запускаемый из *shell-скрипта*, эта внутренняя команда оболочки, естественно, не оказывает (да и не может оказать) никакого влияния.

разница же в поведении вашего *python-скрипта*, **возможно**, вызвана разными наборами опций и параметров, которые вы передаёте этому скрипту в одном и в другом случае.

Comment: Может можно сделать так что бы баш скрипт производил вычисления, потом результат этих вычислений как то вставить в виде параметров питон скриптику. Т.к. речь идёт о бруте crowbar, мне нужно видеть что он выполняется ...

Comment: *Может можно сделать так* — в вопросе вы написали, что у вас именно так и делается.

Answer (score -1):

сравниваю аргументы двух вызовов (я убрал явно совпадающие):

```
python crowbar.py $Report $Potok $Target
python crowbar.py -v -n 2000 -b rdp
```

скорее всего, внутри переменной `$Report` вы передаёте **строку** `-v`, внутри `$Potok` — **строку** `-n 2000`, внутри `$Target` — **строку** `-b rdp`.

и тут, вероятно сказывается либо специфика работы программы `python` (я встречал подобное в некоторых случаях), либо специфика скрипта `crowbar.py`: скрипт «воспринимает» эти **строки** не в качестве опций, а в качестве параметров.

возможно, сможет помочь использование встроенной в оболочку команды `eval`:

```
eval python ...
```

---

**обновление**

если в команде и аргументах не используются символы <kbd>"</kbd>, то попробуйте так (всю команду, включая все аргументы заключите в кавычки):

```
eval "python ..."
```

также можно попробовать «разорвать питонов узел». попробуйте вызывать `crowbar.py` без явного указания интерпретатора.

для этого предварительно файлу надо добавить бит исполнимости:

```
$ chmod +x crowbar.py
```

а затем в bash-скрипте вызывать его по имени:

```
./crowbar.py ...
```

этот же вызов можно попробовать и «завернуть» в `eval`:

```
eval "./crowbar.by ..."
```

Comment: К сожалению ни чего не изменилось

Comment: а вы пробовали в bash-скрипт вписать ровно ту же команду, которую вы выполняете непосредственно в оболочке? без переменных.

Comment: Да, работает. Может привести весь скрипт ?

Comment: bash-скрипт? нет, его содержимое не играет роли. скорее может играть роль содержимое crowbar.py. вы сможете подготовить [краткий завершённый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Переделал вопрос в более подробный

Comment: без crowbar.py или его упрощённой замены, в которой воспроизводится эта ошибка, боюсь, можно лишь гадать на кофейной гуще. кстати, я добавил в ответ ещё пару рецептов «гадания».